# Why using the Taylor series formula for arcsin converges so quickly with x = 1

Tags: c, taylor-series

I took this example from a video in youtube,  where a sen(x) is resolved using this approach, I just changed the formula to an arcsin(x).

I am trying to figure out why this code is not working as expected:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    //#include <float.h>
    #include <math.h>

    int factorial(int x)
    {
        int fac = 1;

        while (x!=0)
        {
            fac= fac*x;
            x--;
        }
        return fac;
    }

    int main()
    {
        int i;
        float x, sum, divisor = 1, dividendo = 1,  temp;

        printf("enter the value of X(in degrees): ");
        scanf("%f", &x);
        //x = x*3.141592/180;

        sum = 0;
        for(i=1; ; i++)
        {
            divisor = (factorial(2*i));
            dividendo = (pow(4,(i)) * pow(factorial(i),2)*(2*i+1));
            temp = (divisor/dividendo)*pow(x,(2*i+1));
            if (temp < FLT_EPSILON)
                          break;
            sum = sum + temp;
            printf("our result = %f\n", sum);
        }  
        printf("reference = %f\n", asin(x));
       // printf("our result = %f\n", sum);

    }
```

Below is the result, and as you may see the output I get is far below from what is expected. the result printed comes from every iteration, and the reference is just to make a comparison between both outcomes.

```
enter the value of X(in degrees): 1
our result = 0.166667
our result = 0.241667
our result = 0.286310
our result = 0.316691
our result = 0.339064
our result = 0.356416
our result = 0.356621
our result = 0.356622
our result = 0.356622
our result = 0.356622
**reference = 1.570796**
```

Comment: Note: `int factorial(int i)` likely only good to `i <= 12` and `factorial(2*i)` only good to `i<=6`.  Surely code loops too far.

Comment: There are a couple issues with this code; the series should start with i=0, and besides x=1 is a singularity of that function, which means that the series might have weird behavior with finite-precision arithmetic.

Comment: Re "*`int factorial(int i)` likely only good to `i <= 12 `*", If so, precalculating the values in an array would be smart.

Comment: @ikegami: Preclaculating these values won't save you from numerical overflow. The usual approach is not to calculate each term of the series separately, but to calculate it from the previous term, so that he factorials and powers contribute only small factors. (But if you're ever going to use only the first 12 factorials, precalculating them might be a good idea.)

Comment: @M Oehm, The fact that the function shouldn't be used at all is not relevant to my comment. Maybe you meant to address the OP?

Comment: @ikegami: Maybe I didn't want to address you personally, but my comment was an addendum to your observation, because the overflow issue is there, smartly precalculated values or not.

Answer (score 4):

The Taylor series for arscin is

```
arcsin(x) = sum n = 0; inf; (2*n)! / (4**n * (n!)**2 * (2*n + 1)) * x**(2*n + 1)
```

where `**` is the power operator and `!` denotes a factorial. As was already noted in comments, an `int` can represent factorials up to `12!` only; a 64-bit `long` can represent factorials up to `20!`. Since you use `(2*n)!`, these limits will be reached quickly.

A better solution to this problem is not to calculate every term separately as given in the formula, but to evolve the term by calculating it from the previous term:

```
term(n + 1) = fact * term(n)
```

Since each term is one large factor, you can do that for each subfactor:

```
       2*(n + 1))!  =  (2*n)!         * (2*n + 1) * (2*n + 2)
        4**(n + 1)  =  4**n           * 4
     ((n + 1)!)**2  =  n!**2          * (n + 1)**2
     2*(n + 1) + 1  =  2*(n + 1)      * (2*n + 3) / (2*n + 1)
x**(2*(n + 1) + 1)  =  x**(2*n + 1)   * x**2
```

Putting all this together:

```
float res = x;        // first term ...
float fact = x;       // ...equals the first factor

for (int n = 0; n < nMax; n++) {
    float old = res;

    // calculate term(n + 1) as per the formulas above

    fact *= (2*n + 1) * (2*n + 2);
    fact /= 4.0 * (n + 1)*(n + 1) * (2*n + 3);
    fact *= x * x * (2*n + 1);

    res += fact;
    if (res == old) break;

    printf("[%d] %f\n", n, res);
}  

printf("ref %f\n", asin(x));
```

(`FLT_EPSILON` is the granularity of floating-point numbers near 1.0. The terms are converging to zero, where the granularity is finer. I've tested whether adding the new term doesn't change the sum as a convergence criterion with a fixed maximum number of iterations, `nMax`.)

This series does not converge well near ±1, where the slope of the function approaches infinity. By Stirling's approximation the nth term approximately equals `1/((2*n+1)*√(πn))`, which converges very slowly. For the nth term to be less than `FLT_EPSILON`, n needs to be greater than 26000. Unfortunately, with that many summations, the finite precision of floating point numbers would prevent the series to converge to the correct answer.